# Meteor: template helpers firing on page back

Tags: meteor

I have a helper for a 'userLayout' template, in which I've defined a current user function. It works fine when I navigate to the template (i'm using flow router with subscriptions in the route). However, when I press 'back' in the browser, the helper fires again.

Why is the helper firing for the template I'm leaving when I press 'back'?

My code for one of the offending helpers is here - I suspect the 'context' attribute:

```
// Return a specific user
findUser: function(context) {
    var id = context.user;
    return Potential_users.find({_id: id});
}
```

EDIT

The view template itself looks like this:

```
<template name="userLayoutView">
    {{#each findUser context}}
       ...
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And that view is getting called dynamically like so:

```
<template name="userLayout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {{#if currentUser context}}
                {{> userLayoutEditCreate context=context}}
            {{else}}
                {{> userLayoutView context=context}}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What does your template code look like?

Comment: I've edited the code. Incidentally, from reading now I seem to have overwritten the currentUser helper... is that terrible?

Comment: Yeah, you should probably rename that.  What do you mean by firing again?  How can you tell?